# solving the integral $\sqrt{\sin(y)}(4-y)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

So the question asked me to find the volume of the area between $\sqrt{\sin(y)}$ and $x=0$ rotated about $y=4$. I came up with the integral

$$\int_0^{\pi}(4-y)\sqrt{\sin(y)}dy$$

I can't figure out how to solve this integral. I can't find a suitable u to do a substitution. How can I find the anti derivative?

Comment: Do you mean the area in one cycle between the graphs of $x=\sqrt{\sin y}$ and $x=0$ rotated around $y=4$? If so, your integral is wrong. Check again how to integrate a solid of revolution.

Comment: Since it says "rotates about...", then your integral should have a $\pi$ term, because the area of each cross section is $\pi r^2$ and in this case, $r(y)$ should be $4 - \sqrt{\sin(y)}$

Answer (score 0):

The anti-derivative of $(4-y)\sqrt sin(x)$ is not an "elementary" function, which means you won't find a solution using usual calculus methods. Are you sure you're evaluating the right integral?